# How to control the width, height and position of a frame after adding a scrollbar using tkinter in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to Python and I'm building a GUI in which I am facing the problem of width, height, and position of a frame. Whenever I'm adding a scrollbar to my frame following issue occurs:

(a) The width and height of the frame get reduced (The original dimension of frame is 945X300).
(b) I want my frame to be placed at a particular location with no dimension reduction of the frame.

Please find the piece of code below:

```
output_frame = Frame(window, width = 945, height=300, bd=0, bg="white", highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black", highlightthickness=1)
output_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor='center')

scroll_v = Scrollbar(output_frame)
scroll_v.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

output_console = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(output_frame, wrap='word', yscrollcommand=scroll_v.set)
output_console.pack(expand=FALSE)

scroll_v.config(command=output_console.yview)
```

Comment: Try adding `output_frame.pack_propagate(0)`.

Comment: @acw1668: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @acw1668 `pack_propagate(0)` is almost never the right solution, especially if you are learning tkinter.  It will work in this very specific case, but it will cause you different problems as you add other widgets.

Comment: Is there a reason you're wanting to force the frame to a specific size, rather than letting tkinter change the size to fit its children? Usually, you should set the ScrolledText widget to be the desired number of rows and columns, and let tkinter size the frame appropriately. Fixing a frame to specific dimensions usually results in a UI that isn't very responsive.